# execute an EXE on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, exe

I have an exe which I call from the command line. Is it possible to execute that file on the server? On the computer if the file is located in the folder abc, I go to folder abc and than I execute the batch. Hw do I do this in C#

Comment: Is the file located on the server, and how are you communicating with it? Your question doesn't make sense in its current context. Try to describe it better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code example below, make sure you have your permissions setup correctly:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process yourProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

// Set the directory   
yourProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Request.MapPath("~/"); //or wherever your file is

// Set the filename
yourProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Request.MapPath("bla.exe"); 

// Start the process    
yourProcess.Start();
```

[ASP Net - Run Application (EXE) from ASP.Net C#](http://mxdev.blogspot.com/2008/09/asp-net-run-application-exe-from-aspnet.html)

Answer (score 0):

In server side code certainly, Process.Start(MyExeFile) will do that but, as long as the user account you are running your stuff on can execute it.